# php how to get between dates and show dynamic data for these dates in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on to show employee attendance details. I am able to show employee in and out time but now i have to show employee leaves also. e.g. if an employee is on leave from 03.01.2022 to 06.01.2022 then it should show CL under these dates.Below are tables and my code.

```
employee_detail

empid     name    team_lead_id
9         ram       6
8         ravi      9   
7         jay       8

emp_attendance

empid    dt          in_time   out_time
7        01-01-2022   9:30      18:00
7        06-01-2022   9:30      18:00
8        01-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
8        03-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
8        04-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
8        05-01-2022   9:30      18:00
8        06-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
9        01-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
9        03-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
9        04-01-2022   9:30      18:00
9        05-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
9        06-01-2022   9:30      18:00 
    
emp_leaves

empid    dt_from         dt_to       leave
 7       03-01-2022     05-01-2022     SL   

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee_detail"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table><tr><th>EmpId</th><th>Name</th>"; 
$list=array();
$month = 1;
$year = 2022;
$date = new DateTime(date('Y').'-'.$month.'-01');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
$last_day_month = $date->format('d');
for($d=1; $d<=$last_day_month; $d++)
{
    
    $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $d, $year); 

    if (date('m', $time)==$month)       
        //$list[]=date('Y-m-d-D', $time);
      $monthDate = date('d.m.Y', $time);
      echo '<th>'.$monthDate.'</th>';
      $monthDateList[] = date('d.m.Y', $time);
    
}
echo "</tr>";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
{
    $empId=$name=$inTime=$outTime=$leaveType='';
    
    $empId = $row['empid'];
    $name =  $row['name'];
    $prevDate = [];
    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$empId."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
    
    
    
    for($k=1; $k<=$last_day_month; $k++)
    {
        
        $time=mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, $k, $year); 
        $monthDate = date('d.m.Y', $time);
        $mDate = date('Y-m-d', $time);
          
          $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM emp_attendance where empid=$empId and dt='$mDate'";    
          $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);  
          $inOut = '';
          $checkHoliday = 1;
          while($row1=$result1->fetch_assoc())
          {
            $date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row1['dt']));
            
            if($monthDate==$date)
            {
                $checkHoliday = 0;
                $inOut .= "InTime:".$row1['in_time']."<br/>OutTime:".$row1['out_time'];
                
            }   
                                
            
          }
          //Check if Employee CL or Not
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM emp_leaves where empid=$empId";  
            $resultRAD = $conn->query($sql2);
            $rowcountRAD = mysqli_num_rows($resultRAD);
            if ($rowcountRAD != 0) 
            {
                while ($rowRAD = mysqli_fetch_array($resultRAD, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                {
                    $dateFrom = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($rowRAD['dt_from']));
                    $dateTo = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($rowRAD['dt_to']));
                    //echo "$monthDate <= $dateFrom <br>";
                    //echo "$monthDate >= $dateTo";
                    if (($dateFrom <= $monthDate) || ($dateFrom >= $dateTo))
                    {  
                        $checkHoliday = 0;
                        $inOut .= "CL";
                    }   
                }   
                
            }
          //Check if it's holiday or not
          if($checkHoliday==0)
          {          
            echo "<td>".$inOut."</td>";
          }
          else
          {
            if(date('w', strtotime($monthDate)) == 0) //check if it's sunday to show Off
            {
                echo "<td>Off</td>";
            }else{
                echo "<td></td>";
            }   
         }  
    }   
    
    echo "</tr>";
    
    
}   
echo "</table>";
```

This is attached response i am getting. In this it should show CL for empid 7 because he was on leave from 03-01-2022 to 05-01-2022. But i am not able to get it.

[image]

Now i am getting this response  for month jan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTVQv.png)

and when i am testing by $month=2; then it's showing CL in response for empid 7 but it should not show beacuse there are no CL of feb month of empid 7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZldD.png)

Comment: Do you have the problem with MySQL (selecting the data with needed filtering) or with PHP (retrieving this data or displaying it)?

Comment: Check your `if` condition again i.e.  `if (($dateFrom <= $monthDate) || ($dateFrom >= $dateTo))` in your code where you are checking `Employee CL or Not`.

Comment: Also, your queries are vulnerable to SQL Injection Attack. Kindly go through this link for better understanding: https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: I am getting issue to display CL for employee. Because when i am testing it for feb month  then it's showing leaves for empid  because in emp_leaves table for empid 7   there is entry  and it's showing same  for feb month also

Comment: I have updated the response above

Comment: i am still  trying to achieve this. can anyone please help